# Trying to get property of non-object error occurs in my controller

Tags: laravel

Was trying to call orders made by a particular user
from my database but get error from my controller reporting from controller..

```
Public function getYourOrders {

    $order = Order::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return View::make('orders.show')->with('order',$order);
}
```

This is where the errorexception is reporting from

Comment: As I try to view in my browser it reports the error exception trying to get property of non-object referring to this line  $order = Order::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get();

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question :-) Make sure the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a logged in user, `Auth::user()->id` would give you that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with framework version 4.1.26+ don't use `Auth::user()->id` to retrieve user's id.

Instead use `id` method:

```
Auth::id();
```

it will take care of returning null if there's no logged in user and it will not execute unnecessary DB query (when using DB driver)